# How do I post different variants of values onto Rx stream?

Tags: rx-swift

I have a stream, say streamA, which updates the UI.

I also subscribe to the changes in the UI, like a switch toggle. For every toggle, I make a network call. The result of the network call may be success, failure or pending. I want to be able to reflect this on the UI appropriately.
Is it possible to map these values onto the streamA so that the UI updates.

```swift
streamA
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (value) in
          self?.updateUI(value)
     })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

uiChangeStream
    .withLatestFrom(streamA, resultSelector: { (uiChange, value) -> Setting? in)
       // some mapping code
    })
    .flatMapLatest {
          return self?.networkCall()
    }
```

What I am trying to figure is, a way to combine the response from network call, the ui-change-trigger and the streamA value at the time of the trigger and bind that to `streamA` so that UI would update.

Comment: What is the source of `streamA` in the first place? You should be able to combine `uiChangeStream` with streamA's source.

Comment: say, `streamA` is from core data.

Answer (score 0):

When developing for Rx you are dealing with causes and effects. Consider each effect in turn and enumerate all the causes that lead to it, then make a stream that goes from the causes to the effect.

You have detailed two effects in the code you posted (updateUI and networkCall) and three causes (streamA, uiChangeStream and the network call's result.)

Let's start with the networkCall effect. Since this leads to another cause (the network call result) we will want to name that stream:

```
let result = uiChangeStream
    .withLatestFrom(streamA, resultSelector: { (uiChange, value) -> Setting? in)
       // some mapping code
    })
    .flatMapLatest {
          return self?.networkCall()
    }
```

You show code that establishes that streamA is a cause for updateUI and tell us in your question that the network call's result is also a cause for it... This means you will have to combine the causes in some way. I'm going to assume a merge is appropriate, but you might need combineLatest instead.

```
Observable.merge(streamA, result.map { /* transform result's type into same as streamA's type */ })
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (value) in
          self?.updateUI(value)
     })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Daniel. The trickiest part here would be the mapping from the `result` stream to `streamA`.

Comment: What if I needed the `uiChangeStream`, `streamA` and the `result` to map `result` to `streamA`'s type? How would I do it then?

Comment: It depends on the exact context but I see you already understand how to use `withLatestFrom` and that is an obvious solution. Another would be to use `combineLatest`.